# How to sort and search a time field in 12 format? DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two fields of type time in postgresql, which saves these values ​​in 24 format (03:30 PM would save 15:30:00).

How can I run a search with a time in format 12 and match it with its equivalent in format 24?

How can I order these fields in 12 format?

the fields are 'ho_inicio' and 'ho_fin'.

My Viewset (I override the list method to search regardless of accents):

```
class HorasEscolaresViewSet(ListModelPagination, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TbledcHora.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HorasEscolaresSerializer
    
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, AliasedOrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = HorasEscolaresFilter
    search_fields = ['id_nivel_academico__nb_nivel_academico', 'nu_hora']
    filterset_fields = ['id_nivel_academico', 'in_status']
    ordering_fields=('id_nivel_academico', 'nu_hora', 'ho_inicio', 'ho_fin')
    ordering= 'id_nivel_academico'
    renderer_classes = (EmberJSONRenderer, )

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    
        if "search" in request.GET:
            if request.GET['search'] != '':
                q_list = []
                q_list.append(Q(id_nivel_academico__nb_nivel_academico__unaccent__icontains=request.GET['search']))

                queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many = True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My serializer:

```
class HorasEscolaresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']
    ho_inicio = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats)
    ho_fin = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats)

    class Meta:
        model = TbledcHora
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```